# ScrollView not scrolling properly?

Tags: android, typescript, react-native

There is a ScrollView in my functional component. I am using an android phone connected to my laptop so that I can see the changes in the phone.

**Problem:**

When I slide on the right side of the phone screen the page scrolls. But when I slide at the center or left side of the phone screen the page does not scroll properly. The page bounces to the top and bottom.

This is my minimalistic code:

```
return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback style={{ flex: 1 }} onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
        <SafeAreaView>
            <Header title="Organizations" navigation={props.navigation} />
            <ScrollView>
                <Block mb={spacing.huge}>
                    <Card>
                         ......
                         <FlatList 
                             .....
                         />
                         ......
                    </Card>
                </Block>
            </ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaView>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>   
)
```

I am getting this error in console:

```
 WARN  VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation - use another VirtualizedList-backed container instead.
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Is there a reason why you nest a `FlatList` inside a `ScrollView`?

Comment: There are Cards inside the Flatlist.

Comment: Does the Scrollview have any function, though? If you remove it, or replace it with a View, does anything break in your layout? FlatList is based on Scrollview, so it also scrolls.

Comment: I used this prop ```nestedScrollEnabled``` inside ```ScrollView```. Now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this prop `nestedScrollEnabled` inside `ScrollView`.